# postgresql: how to flatten a table column to text[]

Tags: postgresql

i got a table that have multiple column, let say "id", "name".

is there a function that can flatten a table column to array of text?

```
 SELECT ARRAY(SELECT row_to_json(t) FROM (SELECT id FROM table) t)
```

this sql is not what i want due to it produce result

```
[{"id":1},{"id":2}]
```

i am looking for a function or query that can produce result as below

```
[1,2]
```

or just simplify, i am looking for a function that can reverse unnest

Comment: If you want just an array of values, then why use `row_to_json` in the first place?

Comment: because that is the nearest result I can get from json function [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `array_agg()`

```
select array_agg(id)
from table
```

Note that this will return an array typed with the data type of the column. So if `id` is an `int` this will return `int[]`